# Dynamic Linq GroupBy Select not working properly

Tags: linq, select, dynamic, group-by

please guide, i am able to work with Dynamic Group by , but when selecting non agrigated fields , i get the following error

No property or field 'name' exists in type 'IGrouping`2'

```
var result311 = (IQueryable)gle1.temptable.Where(a => a.IsAllowed == false && a.Code == "r01");

            var result = result311.GroupBy("new (name, FirstAmountOriginal, SecondAccounting)", "it")
                .Select("new (it.name,Sum(FirstAmountOriginal) as FirstAmountOriginalx, Sum(SecondAccounting) as SecondAccountingx)");
```

Please guide

Comment: The fact you can do this makes my typesafe brain kinda sad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should not group by the fields you want to aggregate and secondly, the grouping creates a grouping `Key` consisting of the fields you group by (in this case one), so you must address this key afterwards:

```
var result = result311.GroupBy("new(name)", "it")
    .Select(@"new (it.Key.name,
                   Sum(FirstAmountOriginal) as FirstAmountOriginalx, 
                   Sum(SecondAccounting) as SecondAccountingx)");
```

Comment: I plow the internet and only this Question Help Me. arnold kheyli mardi